# loading bar on loading new content

Tags: javascript, loading

I have a div which contains a series of design projects. When the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, the javascript detects this and loads new page content into that div.

You can see the website at

http://www.jb-design.me/marchupdate/

The problem I have is that the new content just pauses then loads below. With no feedback for the user that new content is being loaded etc.

What I would like is a div to appear between the current content and the new content (Where the 'spacer' div normally is on my website. And display a loading gif/png. Which would fade out once the new content has loaded. The new content would then appear below fading in...?

Is this possible at all?

I have tried to implement a 'var pageLoadisloaded' but to no use.

I am literally a newbie and have been trailing the web for a solution for the past couple of days and now I thought I would just ask for help!

Thank you in advance

Javascript code below...

```
alreadyloading = false;
nextpage = 2;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        if (alreadyloading == false) {
            var url = "page"+nextpage+".html";
            alreadyloading = true;
            $.post(url, function(data) {
            $('#newcontent').children().last().after(data);
            alreadyloading = false;
            nextpage++;
        });
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you were to have a fixed div to the bottom of the page, and when you were in the conditional to load a new page - you fade it in, and when the new content has been loaded in - you fade it out?

---

Additional assistance

You could try something like this to check if more pages are available - set this up to run after the first ajax - perhaps in the success part of the function:

```
var url = "page"+nextpage+".html";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type:'HEAD',
    error:
        function(){
            // No more pages exist - remove loading
            $('#loading').remove();
        },
    success:
        function(){
            // Good to load another page

        }
});
```

Where I found this:
http://www.ambitionlab.com/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-using-jquery-2010-01-06

Comment: managed to use $("#loading").slideDown(); when loading starts, then $("#loading").slideUp(); when it stops loading. the loading div is fixed, and bottom:0px; attached to it so it is always visible ontop. This works perfect. However... When I load the new content it slides down, then goes away once the loading is complete. But once the user then scrolls to the bottom of the page again, the loading bar appears once more (even if no new content is available to load) Is there a code I can add to detect that 'if there is no new page to load, do not show #loading'? Sorry I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

After you set the alreadyloading variable to true, append a bit of html to the end of the div#newcontent which contains an image that indicates that new content is being loading. Use $(window).ScrollTop() to scroll further down to ensure that this is visible. When the content arrives via Ajax, you can remove the little piece of code you added, and append the new stuff.

Alternatively, use 3 div tags as follows:
1) The already loaded content is kept in the first division.
2) When the scroll-bar reaches the bottom, your function is triggered, which calls a jQuery FadeIn effect for the second division which contains the loading image. Scroll down a bit using the aforementioned function to ensure that it is visible.
3) When the content arrives, put it in the third div and then call a simultaneous FadeIn effect for that, and FadeOut effect for the second division.
4) Once the effect is complete, append the contents of the third division to the first one, and reset the third one.

Comment: I managed to use $("#loading").slideDown(); when loading starts, then $("#loading").slideUp(); when it stops loading.

the loading div is fixed, and bottom:0px; attached to it so it is always visible ontop.

This works perfect. However... 

When I load the new content it slides down, then goes away once the loading is complete. But once the user then scrolls to the bottom of the page again, the loading bar appears once more (even if no new content is available to load)

Is there a code I can add to detect that 'if there is no new page to load, do not show #loading'?
Sorry I am new to this

Comment: Please see www.jb-design.me/marchupdate2/ for the website. The images are not of my work work yet, just for functionality...